# Using \MakeUppercase on expanded macro with argument

Tags: macros, expansion

I would like to have the first letter in an expanded macro shifted to upper case but I can not seem to manage this. In the minimal example below, I would like the two rows to produce the same output, first letter capitalized, but the second row has all letters in lower case.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

%%% Begin document
\begin{document}

\begin{acronym}
\acro{rms}{root mean square}
\end{acronym}

\section{Text}
\MakeUppercase root mean square (\acs{rms})

\expandafter\MakeUppercase\expandafter\empty\ac{rms}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

How can I solve this?

Edit:

It appears that the minimal example was to minimal. The suggested solution does not work with the rest of the document. Here is a more complete minimal example.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage{acronym}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newif\ifAcUpper
\AcUpperfalse

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\AC@@acro}{] #3}{] \expandafter\MakeUppercase #3}{}{}
\patchcmd{\AC@@acro}{] #3}{] \expandafter\MakeUppercase #3}{}{}
\makeatother

\newif\ifACR
\ACRfalse

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\acx}{\protect\@acx}%
\newcommand{\@acx}[1]{%
\ifAC@dua
    \acl{#1}%
\else
    \expandafter\ifx\csname ac@#1\endcsname\AC@used
       \acs{#1}%
    \else
       \acl{#1}%
    \fi
\fi
}

\newcommand{\acy}{\protect\@acy}%
\newcommand{\@acy}[1]{%
  \ifACR
    \acl{#1}%
  \else
    \acf{#1}
  \fi
}

\newcommand{\dac}{\protect\@dac}%
\newcommand{\@dac}[1]{%
  \ifAC@dua
    the \acl{#1}%
  \else
    \expandafter\ifx\csname ac@#1\endcsname\AC@used
      \acs{#1}%
    \else
      the \acf{#1}%
    \fi
  \fi
}

\newcommand{\Dac}{\protect\@Dac}%
\newcommand{\@Dac}[1]{%
  \ifAC@dua
    The \acl{#1}%
  \else
    \expandafter\ifx\csname ac@#1\endcsname\AC@used
      \acs{#1}%
    \else
     The \acf{#1}%
    \fi
  \fi
}

\newcommand{\Ac}{\@Ac}%
\newcommand{\@Ac}[1]{%
  \ifAC@dua
    \acl{#1}%
  \else
    \expandafter\ifx\csname ac@#1\endcsname\AC@used
      \acs{#1}%
    \else
        \expandafter\MakeUppercase\expandafter\empty\ac{#1}
    \fi
  \fi
}
\makeatother

%%% Begin document
\begin{document}

\begin{acronym}
\ACRtrue
\acro{dc}[DC]{Direct Current}
\acro{pu}[p.u.]{per unit}
\acro{rms}[rms]{root-mean-square}
\acro{b}[$B$]{magnetic flux density}
\acro{hor}[$H$]{horizontal component of the \acx{b}}
\acro{d}[$D$]{electric displacement of \acx{b}}
\acro{h}[$H$]{magnetic field intensity}
\acro{rdc}[$R_{DC}$]{\acy{dc} resistance}
\acro{phi}[$\phi$]{magnetic flux}
\acro{sbase}[$S_{base}$]{\acy{pu} power base}
\acro{ubase}[$U_{base}$]{\acy{pu} voltage base}
\acro{phibase}[$\Phi_{base}$]{\acy{pu} \acx{phi} base}
\acro{udc}[$U_{DC}$]{\acy{dc} voltage}
\acro{idc}[$I_{DC}$]{\acy{dc} current}
\ACRfalse
\end{acronym} 

\section{Text}
\MakeUppercase root mean square (\acs{rms})

\Ac{rms}

\end{document}
```

For which the output looks like this

[image: Output2]

I would like the `\Ac` command to produce a line starting with a capital letter and all descriptions in the list to do the same.

Comment: What's `\empty` supposed to do?

Comment: `\ac` does not work by exapnsion, and certainly would require more than one expansion step as produced by `\expandafter` but also you are just passing `\empty` as the argument to `\MakeUppercase`

Comment: I do not know if `glossaries` could be an option, but with this package you  can define `\newacronym{rms}{rms}{root mean square}` and then use  `\gls{rms}` or `\Gls{rms}`  at the start of a sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to insert the uppercasing into the result of `\ac`, but `\ac` does not work by expansion so `\expandafter` does not help. (If it had worked by expansion, your expression would still have been wrong as it passes `\empty` to `\MakeUppercase`)

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 10pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[printonlyused]{acronym}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

%%% Begin document
\begin{document}
\DeclareRobustCommand\zz[1]{#1}
\begin{acronym}

\acro{rms}{\zz{r}oot mean square}

\end{acronym}

\section{Text}
\MakeUppercase root mean square (\acs{rms})

%\expandafter\MakeUppercase\expandafter\empty\ac{rms}

{\renewcommand\zz{\MakeUppercase}\ac{rms}}

\end{document}
```

Comment: It seems that my minimal example was to minimal. This solution works fine on its own but not in combination with the rest of my document. I will edit the question.